# Customise Default Output Of JSON in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nvd3.js, expandoobject

I am using dynamic ExpandoObject() to create some json required for an NVD3/d3.js visualisation.

The nvd3 library is pretty explicit in what it needs with regards to data identifiers.

Exactly the json i need is the following -

```
[{
    key: "AgeGroups",
    values: [{
        "label": "<20",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "label": ">20 <29",
        "value": 160
    }, {
        "label": ">29 <39",
        "value": 240
    }]
}]
```

**Note:** the string 'key' must be lowercase and values must be pluralized.

With the following c#, I am able to get very close -

```
ageDemoJson.AgeGroups = new object[]
            {
              new { label = "<20", value =  lessThan20 },
              new { label = ">20 <29", value = between20and29 },
              new { label = ">29 <39", value = between29and39 },
            };
```

This outputs the following

```
    [{
    Key: "AgeGroups",
    Value: [{
        "label": "<20",
        "value": 0
    }, {
        "label": ">20 <29",
        "value": 160
    }, {
        "label": ">29 <39",
        "value": 240
    }]
}]
```

With this output, I need to customise the default behaviour of ExpandoObject and make the string **'Key' become 'key'** and the string **'value' become 'values'**

Is there anyway of doing this?

Of course I can work around this by parsing the json to string and replacing what I need in javascript, but would like if I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using asp.net core you can change the JSON serialization by adding this line:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        // Force Camel Case to JSON
        opts.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

Or you can achive the same result by using Newtonsoft's Json.NET with this option:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        yourObjectToSerialize,
        new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this made the json completely different to what I need.